# Setting adMob ad at the bottom of a layout

Tags: android, layout, admob

I can't seem to get my adview to appear at the very bottom. It appears right after the last button in my xml layout. I've tried everything from new layouts to weight's and it won't work for me. If you could help, that'd be great!

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/reason_1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="75dp"
            android:background="@drawable/button"
            android:text="@string/reason_1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/reason_2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="75dp"
            android:background="@drawable/button"
            android:text="@string/reason_2" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/reason_3"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="75dp"
            android:background="@drawable/button"
            android:text="@string/reason_3" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/reason_button"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="75dp"
            android:background="@drawable/button_layout"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_credit_cards"
            android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_credit_cards"
            android:text="@string/reason_button_string" />

        <com.google.ads.AdView
            android:id="@+id/adView"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            ads:adSize="BANNER"
            ads:adUnitId="xxxxxx"
            ads:loadAdOnCreate="true" >
        </com.google.ads.AdView>
    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 1):

The idea is to use RelativeLayout and place the ad at the bottom. Then place the Scrollview above it, so the ad always is at the bottom of the screen. Don't use fill_parent, it's deprecated.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<com.google.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="xxxxxx"
    ads:loadAdOnCreate="true" >
</com.google.ads.AdView>

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@id/adView" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <Button
        android:id="@+id/reason_1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button"
        android:text="@string/reason_1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/reason_2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button"
        android:text="@string/reason_2" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/reason_3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button"
        android:text="@string/reason_3" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/reason_button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button_layout"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_credit_cards"
        android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_credit_cards"
        android:text="@string/reason_button_string" />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

@svenoaks solved my answer 3/4ths of the way. Just had to fine tune it. Here's the restuls.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<com.google.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="xxxxxx"
    ads:loadAdOnCreate="true" >
</com.google.ads.AdView>



    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <Button
        android:id="@+id/reason_1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button"
        android:text="@string/reason_1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/reason_2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button"
        android:text="@string/reason_2" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/reason_3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button"
        android:text="@string/reason_3" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/reason_button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button_layout"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_credit_cards"
        android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_credit_cards"
        android:text="@string/reason_button_text" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```